# Using C in Swift - strlcpy - Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>'

Tags: c, swift, swift3, unsafe-pointers, unsafemutablepointer

I am trying to use strlcpy in Swift 3.0, but keep getting the error "Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer!'"

Here is my code

```
func login(portal: String, username: String, password: String) {
    var loginEvent = VidyoClientInEventLogIn()
    let portalCArray = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: (portal as NSString).utf8String!)
    withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &loginEvent.portalUri) {
        strlcpy($0, portalCArray, MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: $0))
    }
}
```

where VidyoClientInEventLogIn is:

```
typedef struct VidyoClientInEventLogIn_
{
    /*! Portal URI, i.e. "https://example.test.com" */
    char portalUri[URI_LEN];
} VidyoClientInEventLogIn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C arrays are imported to Swift as tuples. But the memory layout of
C structures is preserved in Swift, therefore you can use the address
of the first tuple element `loginEvent.portalUri.0` (which has type `CChar` aka `Int8`)
as the target address.

Also you can pass a Swift `String` directly as argument to a function
taking a `UnsafePointer<CChar>` parameter, a temporary C string
representation is created automatically.

This simplifies things to:

```
func login(portal: String, username: String, password: String) {
    var loginEvent = VidyoClientInEventLogIn()
    strlcpy(&loginEvent.portalUri.0, portal, MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: loginEvent.portalUri))
}
```